# How to calculate slug with URL segment of parent object?

Tags: typo3, slug

I would like to calculate the slug automatically by using the parent object. Like with the pages where the parent pages are part of the slug.

In my extension I have an object hierarchy like 'journal' > 'volume' > 'issue' > 'article' etc. I want the slug to be something like:

/volume/5/issue/7/headline-of-the-article

How can this be done?

[TYPO3 v11]

Comment: You need a routeEnhancers routing config and a according additionalArguments param in the  fluid <f:link:action> tag. 

SEE:  https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Routing/AdvancedRoutingConfiguration.html#extbase-plugin-enhancer

Comment: Without any routing configuration, your links should look like this in FE:
?tx_yourext_pi1[controller]=YourControllerName&tx_yourext_pi1[action]=show&tx_yourext_pi1[journal123&tx_yourext_pi1[volume]=123&tx_yourext_pi1[issue]=123&tx_yourext_pi1[article]=123

Comment: This does not help me because I want the slug of the article itself to take slugs of other objects into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate a slug for your custom object you need following:

1.A path-segment field in your database. Add to your article models SQL:

```
path_segment varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
```

2.Add the field to the article models TCA:

```
'path_segment' => [
    'exclude' => true,
    'label' => 'URL path segment',
    'l10n_mode' => 'exclude',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'slug',
        'generatorOptions' => [
            'fields' => ['title'],  // Title of your article
            'fieldSeparator' => '/',
            'prefixParentPageSlug' => false,
            'postModifiers' => [
                \VENDOR\ExtName\PostModifier\MyCoolPostModifier::class . '->modifySlug'
            ],
        ],
        'fallbackCharacter' => '-',
        'eval' => 'uniqueInSite',
        'default' => ''
    ],
],
```

If the postmodifier does not work as described. Check out the docs. There it sais the postmodifier should be registered as a hook:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Slug/Properties/GeneratorOptions.html#confval-generatorOptions-postModifiers

3.A postmodifier class with a modifySlug method:

The method receives an parameter with the following values:

```
[
    'slug' // ... the slug to be used
    'workspaceId' // ... the workspace ID, "0" if in live workspace
    'configuration' // ... the configuration of the TCA field
    'record' // ... the full record to be used
    'pid' // ... the resolved parent page ID
    'prefix' // ... the prefix that was added
    'tableName' // ... the table of the slug field
    'fieldName' // ... the field name of the slug field
];
```

There you can load the parent objects of your article and then generate the slug. At the end return the modified slug.
If you need help with that, give me a hint in the comments.

**EDIT:**

Here is an example postModifier that should fit your requirements:

```
<?php
namespace VENDOR\ExtName\PostModifier;

use VENDOR\ExtName\Domain\Repository\ArticleRepository;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\PersistenceManager;

class SlugPostModifier
{
    public function modifySlug(array $data): string
    {
        // You will need the uid of the articles Record
        $recordUid = $data['record']['uid'];

        // To load the Object you will need the object manager and persistence manager
        $objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class);
        $persistenceManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(PersistenceManager::class);

        // Instanciate your article repository and inject the persistence manager
        $articleRepository = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ArticleRepository::class, $objectManager);
        $articleRepository->injectPersistenceManager($persistenceManager);

        // Fetch the article object by record uid
        $article = $articleRepository->findByUid($recordUid);

        // Load the articles parent objects - somehow like (Depends on your models)
        $issue = $article->getIssue();
        $volume = $issue->getVolume();
        $journal = $volume->getJournal();

        // Load the path segments of the articles parent objects
        $articleSlug = $data['slug'];
        $issueSlug = $issue->getPathSegment();
        $volumeSlug = $volume->getPathSegment();
        $journalSlug = $journal->getPathSegment();

        /**
         * If your articles parent objects do not have path segments,
         * then you could also load the title-fields.
         * But be aware that you than have to do several string operations.
         * Like strtolower(), str_replace() etc....
         * to replace capitals letters and special characters like german umlauts i.e.
         */

        return "$journalSlug/$volumeSlug/$issueSlug/$articleSlug";
    }
}
```

Comment: The 'postModifier' seems to be my way. I didn't know that one. Thank you, I will report how I managed to solve the problem with it.

Comment: Can you direct me to an example hook file?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example for a postModifier. Would be great if you would mark the answer as accepted and give me a up. ;-)

Answer (score -2):

Today I wrote a similar thing for my cars extension.
Try this code in your site config yaml file:

```
routeEnhancers:
  CardealerPlugin:
    type: Extbase
    extension: Cardealer
    plugin: Pi1
    routes:
      - routePath: /
        _controller: 'Cardealer::list'
      - routePath: '/Make/{makePlaceholder}/Model/{modelPlaceholder}'
        _controller: 'Cardealer::list'
        _arguments:
          makePlaceholder: make
          modelPlaceholder: model
    defaultController: 'Cardealer::list'
    aspects:
      makePlaceholder:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_cardealer_domain_model_make
        routeFieldName: uid
      modelPlaceholder:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_cardealer_domain_model_model
        routeFieldName: uid
```

Fluid template links:

```
<f:link.action action="list" arguments="{make: '44', model: '429'}">Opel Astra</f:link.action>
```

Good luck!

Comment: This is perhaps a good way to implement the routing. But the question was how to calculate a slug. ;-)